# Text in singleLine TextView inside ListView inside HorizontalScrollView is cut off

Tags: android, listview, textview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying for some hours now to get rid of the following problem and I search and applied the methods I found here and on other sites, but the result is still bad. Please have a look at the following screenshot:[Screenshot of cut off text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QitF4.png)

This is my xml part:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="367dp"
    android:layout_height="355dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_search">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_results"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_search" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this is what I have written in my Java file:

`

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleList) {

            @Override                
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            // Get the Item from ListView

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            // Set the text size in ListView for each item
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,40);
            tv.setSingleLine(true);
            tv.setMaxLines(1);
            tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
            tv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            //tv.setEllipsize(MARQUEE);
            //tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1000);


            // Return the view
            return view;
        }
    };`
```

As you can see I already tried the marquee option, but it did not show any effects.
Can anyone if he/she knows where to read about a possible solution, because the sources I found could not help me at all. If you have any suggestions, I would be happy to read them. I want to thank anyone in advance for their help. This is a university project and my first Android Application - some complications here and there ^^.

I was wondering if a TextView or a ListView or a HorizontalScollView has a limit in the width and if so where it can be expanded if that is an option.

Cheers
Durim

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer now.

The HorizontalScrollView was creating a scrollable container that was exactly as width as the first entry of my ListView.

The Solutions I found:

**1)**
You bring your longest line to the first place in your list (depending on the font family that is used it still could make problems).

**2)**
I set the font family to "MONOSPACE" for all TextView inside my ListView and added spaces " " to the first line to make its number of characters equal to the number of characters of the longest line.

I hope this helps anyone some day. If you have any questions concerning this topic, let me know.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

at listview.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it is not helping. I also tried to set the layout_width from the textViews to "wrap_content" but no change noticed.